# How to add forgot password link below Signin in Dialog box in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, android-alertdialog

[image: Screenshot of dialog box]

I am creating sign in form within a Alert Dialog box but In this Dialog box i want to add forgot Password link below sign in which will link me to another Activity. I tried many modifications but it crashes .I am using Firebase Authentication in this App.App crashes when i modify the code In main activity and gives errors.
below is my Main java code.

```
 package com.techno.giants.technogiants;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText;
import com.techno.giants.technogiants.Model.User;

import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyConfig;
import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyContextWrapper;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RelativeLayout rootLayout;
    Button btnSignIn,btnRegister;
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    FirebaseDatabase db;
    DatabaseReference users;
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Arkhip_font.ttf")
                .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                .build());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //init firebase
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        db=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        users=db.getReference("Users");


        btnRegister=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        btnSignIn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
        rootLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);

        //Event
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showRegisterDialog();
            }
        });
        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showLoginDialog();
            }
        });
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (auth.getCurrentUser() !=null){
                    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Welcome.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        };

    }

    private void showLoginDialog() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("SIGN IN");
        dialog.setMessage("Please use Email to Sign In");

        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View login_layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_login,null);

        final MaterialEditText edtEmail=login_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
        final MaterialEditText edtPassword=login_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);


        dialog.setView(login_layout);

        //set button
        dialog.setPositiveButton("SIGN IN", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                dialogInterface.dismiss();
                //check validation
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtEmail.getText().toString())) {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Please enter Email Address", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtPassword.getText().toString())) {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Please enter Password", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    return;
                }
                if (edtPassword.getText().toString().length() < 6) {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Password too short", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    return;
                }

                //login
                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(edtEmail.getText().toString(),edtPassword.getText().toString())
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Welcome.class));
                                finish();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Snackbar.make(rootLayout,"Failed sign In"+e.getMessage(),Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

        });

        dialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });


        dialog.show();

    }



    private void showRegisterDialog() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("REGISTER");
        dialog.setMessage("Please use Email to register");

        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View register_layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_register,null);

        final MaterialEditText edtEmail=register_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
        final MaterialEditText edtPassword=register_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
        final MaterialEditText edtName=register_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtName);
        final MaterialEditText edtPhone=register_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtPhone);
        final MaterialEditText edtCollege=register_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtCollege);

        dialog.setView(register_layout);

        //set button
        dialog.setPositiveButton("REGISTER", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                dialogInterface.dismiss();
                //check validation
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtEmail.getText().toString()))
                {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout,"Please enter Email Address",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    return;
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtPhone.getText().toString()))
                {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout,"Please enter Phone Number",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    return;
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtPassword.getText().toString()))
                {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout,"Please enter Password",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    return;
                }
                if (edtPassword.getText().toString().length()<6)
                {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout,"Password too short",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    return;
                }
                //register new user
                auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(edtEmail.getText().toString(),edtPassword.getText().toString())
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                                //save user to db
                                User user=new User();
                                user.setEmail(edtEmail.getText().toString());
                                user.setName(edtName.getText().toString());
                                user.setPhone(edtPhone.getText().toString());
                                user.setPassword(edtPassword.getText().toString());
                                user.setCollege(edtCollege.getText().toString());



                                //use email to key
                                users.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                        .setValue(user)
                                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                                Snackbar.make(rootLayout,"Register success",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                                        .show();
                                            }
                                        })
                                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                                Snackbar.make(rootLayout,"Failed "+e.getMessage(),Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                                        .show();
                                            }
                                        });
                            }
                        })

                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Snackbar.make(rootLayout,"Failed "+e.getMessage(),Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
        dialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        auth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you can't add a TextView then set an OnClickListener just like MaterialEditText edtEmail which starts the new Activity? There should be no reason why you can't as there's already MaterialEditText edtEmail.

Comment: I tried but that dont work

Answer (score 1):

**Could you Input Log File?**

Some of the special characters(.) are not entered in FireBase.